# PHP SDK Moip: Qual tag usar para Bancos quando em Débito online?

Tags: php

No exemplo a seguir, para débito com Banco Itaú, funciona perfeitamente:

```
$payment = $order->payments()
    ->setOnlineBankDebit('341', $expiration_date, 'http://localhost/federais/')
    ->execute();

    $redirect = $payment->getLinks()->getLink('payOnlineBankDebitItau');

    header("location:$redirect");
```

Mas para o Banco do Brasil não funciona, qual nome devo colocar?

```
$payment = $order->payments()
    ->setOnlineBankDebit('001', $expiration_date, 'http://localhost/federais/')
    ->execute();

    $redirect = $payment->getLinks()->getLink('payDebitOnline');

    header("location:$redirect");
```

E para os outros bancos? Bradesco, Barisul e outros?

Tá tentei `payDebitOnlineBrasil` e outros e nada funciona. Alguém já trabalhou com o SDK do Moip para débito online pode me ajudar?

Acabo de testar o do Bradesco: `payDebitOnlineBradesco` e deu certo. Mas e os outros bancos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qual a versão do SDK você está utilizando? Ao que me parece a v2 só tem o suporte para transferência bancária com o Banco Itaú, de acordo com a [página de suporte](https://suporte.moip.com.br/hc/pt-br/articles/206766687-Quais-os-meios-de-pagamentos-oferecidos-pelo-Moip-) deles:

> Meios de pagamentos aceitos para E-commerce e Marketplace
>
> - Cartões de crédito: Visa, MasterCard, Hiper, Dinners Club, American Express, Elo e Hipercard.
> - Débito em conta: O débito em conta com Banco Itaú.
>
>   Em uma versão um pouco mais antiga (v1) temos também o Banco Bradesco, Banco Banrisul e o Banco do Brasil.

Comment: É a versão 2 mesmo. Então só Itau. Entendi. Obrigado @gmsantos.